# Could not update ICEauthority file, password not working in terminal

Tags: password

I Tried to login and got `could not update ICEauthority file` error message. tried to fix it in terminal after pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd>, but it won't recognize my password to let me do anything.

Answer (score 0):

1. Reset **your** user account password using the guide [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password). (Not the root password)
2. Whenever you login to the cosole/terminal/text session as root while resetting the password, issue the following command to remove the ICEauthority file.

   > rm /home/**your-user-name**/.ICEauthority